# How to color this region produced by tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using xelatex and I want to color the region enclosed by y=f(x), y=g(x) and the lines x=a and x=b in the code below (just like the picture below). How can I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,>=triangle 45] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->,>=triangle 45] (0,-2.2) -- (0,3.2) node [above] {$y$};
\draw[very thick] (-1.5,.5) to [out=300,in=180] (-.5,-.5)
to [out=0,in=180] (3,2.5)
to [out=360,in=140] (4.5,2) ;
\draw[very thick] (-1.5,-1.5) to [out=350,in=240] (4.5,1) ;
\draw[very thick] (4.2,0)--(4.2,2.2);
\node at (4.2,0) [below] {$b$};
\draw[very thick] (-1,0)--(-1,-1.55);
\node at (-1,0) [above] {$a$};
\node at (1.5,2.2) [above] {$y=f(x)$};
\node at (2,-1.5) [right] {$y=g(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the results for [\[tikz-pgf\] color region](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btikz-pgf%5D+color+region)? There might be some questions and answers that will help you. Furthermore, have you already tried any attempt to fill the region?

Comment: Do you know the equations for f(x) and g(x) (or could you make one up)?

Comment: @Jake No. I don't have their formulas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip(-1,-5)rectangle(4.2,5);
\clip (-1.5,.5) to [out=300,in=180] (-.5,-.5)
to [out=0,in=180] (3,2.5)
to [out=360,in=140] (4.5,2) --++(0,-5)--(-1,-5)--cycle;
\fill[red] (-1.5,-1.5) to [out=350,in=240] (4.5,1)--++(0,5)--(-1,5)--cycle;
\end{scope}
\draw [->,>=triangle 45] (-2,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw [->,>=triangle 45] (0,-2.2) -- (0,3.2) node [above] {$y$};
\draw[very thick] (-1.5,.5) to [out=300,in=180] (-.5,-.5)
to [out=0,in=180] (3,2.5)
to [out=360,in=140] (4.5,2) ;
\draw[very thick] (-1.5,-1.5) to [out=350,in=240] (4.5,1) ;
\draw[very thick] (4.2,0)--(4.2,2.2);
\node at (4.2,0) [below] {$b$};
\draw[very thick] (-1,0)--(-1,-1.55);
\node at (-1,0) [above] {$a$};
\node at (1.5,2.2) [above] {$y=f(x)$};
\node at (2,-1.5) [right] {$y=g(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can make the code even better by using named coordinates and reuse of paths.

I still haven't figured out an automatic way to determine the extremal values of the curves, so the path appendices

> --++(0,-5)--(-1,-5)--cycle

and

> --++(0,5)--(-1,5)--cycle

can be replaced by automatically correct values.

Comment: @user2553 Thanks for your reply, but I want to color the region like the picture above (I added a picture).

Comment: Sorry, there was some copyediting error. Corrected the answer.

Comment: @user2553 thanks for your update. Could you please explain what `scope` and `clip` do?

Comment: `scope` defines a "subenvironment" that is usually uses to set tikz parameters for several `\draw`, etc. In this example, it's only used to restrict the `clip`. Without it, the `clip` would affect the whole tikzpicture after the `clip`-command.

`clip` defines a region outside of which nothing will be drawn. In my answer, the first `clip` restricts the drawing area to -1≤x≤4.2. The second `clip` restricts the drawing area to y≤f(x).

Comment: @user2553 A problem: when using your code, I get extra spaces above and below the graph, but If I delete `\begin{scope}
\clip(-1,-5)rectangle(4.2,5);
\clip (-1.5,.5) to [out=300,in=180] (-.5,-.5)
to [out=0,in=180] (3,2.5)
to [out=360,in=140] (4.5,2) --++(0,-5)--(-1,-5)--cycle;
\fill[red] (-1.5,-1.5) to [out=350,in=240] (4.5,1)--++(0,5)--(-1,5)--cycle;
\end{scope}`, everything will be OK. I'm aware of `\vspace{...}`, but I want to know the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: If you delete the whole scope, then nothing will be filled.

The spaces are the result of the first clip, which defines a rectangle, that will be put into the tikzpicture and thus takes up space. You can regulate the space by adjusting this rectangle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7758/discussion-between-toscho-and-vahid-damanafshan)